# Make a count of rows in query table

Tags: mysql

I have 4 different tables:

```
username table:
| uid | username | user_type|
+-----+----------+----------+
| 1   | Aaron    | CT       |
| 2   | Ahmad    | FT       |
| 3   | Akir     | CT       |
| 4   | Adelyn   | FT       |
| 4   | Adeeb    | AP       |
| 4   | Aizad    | FT       |
| 4   | Adeline  | AP       |


proc_leader table:
| projectNo | process | proc_leader|
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Aaron      |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Ahmad      |

proc_checker table:
| projectNo | process | proc_checker |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Adeeb        |
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Adeline      |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Aizad        |

proc_staff table:
| projectNo | process | proc_staff |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Aaron      |
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Adelyn     |
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Ahmad      |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Akir       |
```

Then I `UNION` all tables to create one table and get `user_type`  of each user:

```
SELECT a.*FROM(
 (
   SELECT * FROM proc_leader t1 LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
   ) t2 ON t1.proc_leader = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_leader
 ) UNION(
   SELECT * FROM proc_checker t1 LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
   ) t2 ON t1.proc_checker = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_checker
 ) UNION(
   SELECT * FROM proc_staff t1 LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
   ) t2 ON t1.proc_staff = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_staff
 )
) AS a
ORDER BY a.projectNo
```

For now my output is:

```
| projectNo | process | proc_leader | user_type |
+-----------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Adeeb       |    AP     |
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Adelyn      |    FT     |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Ahmad       |    FT     |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Aizad       |    FT     |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Akir        |    CT     |
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Aaron       |    CT     |
| 170001    | ANM BLD | Adeline     |    AP     |
| 170001    | BGD COL | Ahmad       |    FT     |
```

Then what I want to do is to count `user_type` for each process and put it in one cell. So I want my output to be like that:

```
| projectNo | process |     count         |
+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 170001    | ANM BLD | 1(CT)+2(AP)+2(FT) |
| 170001    | BGD COL | 2(FT)+1(CT)       |
```

I know I can use `GROUP_COncat()` to put it in one cell, but how can I do the calculation from received table?

Comment: Project number `170001` has both `ANM BLD` and `BGD COL` as processes, so why is only `ANM BLD` process being shown in your expected results?  Your data doesn't appear to be normalized.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, there is a typo in project number. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    projectNo,
    process,
    GROUP_CONCAT(col separator '+') `count`
from (
SELECT
    projectNo,
    process,
    concat(count(*),'(',user_type,')') col
FROM(
 (
   SELECT * FROM proc_leader t1 LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
   ) t2 ON t1.proc_leader = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_leader
 ) UNION(
   SELECT * FROM proc_checker t1 LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
   ) t2 ON t1.proc_checker = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_checker
 ) UNION(
   SELECT * FROM proc_staff t1 LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
   ) t2 ON t1.proc_staff = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_staff
 )
) AS a
group by projectNo, process, user_type
) t group by projectNo, process;
```

Comment: MySQL uses concat(...) not +

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `LEFT JOIN` each table contained in the `UNION`.  Rather, just use a single `UNION` subquery and join that to the `username` table.

In the query below, I report all three user types for each `projectNo`, `process` group, even if the count be zero.  If you really don't want user types to appear at all in the event that their count be zero, you will have to do a bit more work than this.

```
SELECT t2.projectNo,
       t2.process,
       CONCAT(
           CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_type = 'CT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(50)), '(CT)+',
           CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_type = 'AP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(50)), '(AP)+',
           CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_type = 'FT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(50)), '(FT)')
           AS count
FROM username t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT projectNo, process, proc_leader AS username
    FROM proc_leader
    UNION ALL
    SELECT projectNo, process, proc_checker
    FROM proc_checker
    UNION ALL
    SELECT projectNo, process, proc_staff
    FROM proc_staff
) t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username
GROUP BY t2.projectNo,
         t2.process
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: There are 6 user_types in username table. It may changed depends on user. And I dont need it to be zero, I just need to show count of assigned people.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy You can easily add more terms to the query I gave you if you want.  Your sample data only shows three terms, hence my answer has three terms.  The answer I gave is more efficient than the answer you accepted.

Comment: But if I add all six types, in final table it will display all six types with 0. And I do not need to show zero, just count of the assigned types. Also user_type can be changed or added new. So I will have to change query every time after changes being made in username table